# Producer-consumer inter-thread communication

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer

having trouble with inter-thread communication and "solved" it by using "dummy messages" all over the place. Is this a bad idea? What are possible solutions?

Example Problem i have.

main thread starts a thread for processing and inserting records into database.
main thread reads a possibly huge file and puts one record (object) after another into a blockingqueue. processing thread reads from queue and does work.

How do I tell "processing thread" to stop? 
Queue can be empty but work is not done and the main thread does not now either when processing thread has finished work and can't interrupt it.

So processing thread does

```
while (queue.size() > 0 || !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    MyObject object= queue.poll(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (object != null) {
        String data = object.getData();
        if (data.equals("END")) {
            break;
        }
    // do work
    }
}
// clean-up
synchronized queue) {
    queue.notifyAll();
}
return;
```

and main thread

```
// ...start processing thread...
while(reader.hasNext(){
    // ...read whole file and put data in queue...
}
MyObject dummy = new MyObject();
dummy.setData("END");
queue.put(dummy);
//Note: empty queue here means work is done
while (queue.size() > 0) {
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.wait(500); // over-cautios locking prevention i guess
    }
}
```

Note that insertion must be in same transaction and transaction can't be handled
by main thread.

What would be a better way of doing this?
(I'm learning and don't want to start "doing it the wrong way")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These dummy message is valid. It is called "poison". Something that the producer sends to the consumer to make it stop.

Other possibility is to call Thread.interrupt() somewhere in the main thread and catch and handle the InterruptedException accordingly, in the worker thread.

Comment: Ok. How would I use this if the type of objects passed don't have a String field that can easily be used for this? What if any text could be valid data and hence could equal the poison? Use a GUID?

Comment: Ideally you would change the MyObject class and add a method isPoison() there. How this method determines if the object is a poison or not is up to you, may be a simple thing like comparing if the message is null, empty or if the message was explicitly created as a poison. A idea would to refactor MyObject to be an interface with two implementations, a MessageObject which always return false in the isPoison() method and a PoisonMessage, that always return true. But this deeply depend of what exactly you are doing, and better solutions may exists given your real context.

Answer (score 2):

> "solved" it by using "dummy messages" all over the place. Is this a
>   bad idea? What are possible solutions?

It's not a bad idea, it's called "Poison Pills" and is a reasonable way to stop a thread-based service.

But it only works when the number of producers and consumers is known.

In code you posted, there are two threads, one is "main thread", which produces data, the other is "processing thread", which consumes data, the "Poison Pills" works well for this circumstance.

But to imagine, if you also have other producers, how does consumer know when to stop (only when all producers send "Poison Pills"), you need to know exactly the number of all the producers, and to check the number of "Poison Pills" in consumer, if it equals to the number of producers, which means all producers stopped working, then consumer stops.

In "main thread", you need to catch the `InterruptedException`, since if not, "main thread" might not able to set the "Poison Pill". You can do it like below,

```
...
try {
    // do normal processing
} catch (InterruptedException e) { /*  fall through  */  }
finally {
    MyObject dummy = new MyObject();
    dummy.setData("END");
    ...
}
...
```

Also, you can try to use the `ExecutorService` to solve all your problem.

(It works when you just need to do some works and then stop when all are finished)

```
void doWorks(Set<String> works, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
    throws InterruptedException {
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    try {
        for (final String work : works)
            exec.execute(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        ...
                    }
                });
    } finally {
        exec.shutdown();
        exec.awaitTermination(timeout, unit);
    }
}
```

> I'm learning and don't want to start "doing it the wrong way"

You might need to read the Book: Java Concurrency in Practice. Trust me, it's the best.

Comment: I know about executor service but the reading of the data and the processing (validation) and inserting can not be in the same task or method because they should all run in the same Database transaction. If you understand what I mean.

Comment: OK, I get that, `ExecutorService` is just my general recommendation, use it or not according to your requirements. But be careful to catch all the exceptions, if some exceptions are uncaught, you may lose the chance to set the "Poison Pills".

Answer (score 0):

What you could do (which I did in a recent project) is to wrap the queue and then add a `'isOpen()'`method.

```
class ClosableQ<T> {

   boolean isOpen = true;

   private LinkedBlockingQueue<T> lbq = new LinkedBlockingQueue<T>();

   public void put(T someObject) {
      if (isOpen) {
         lbq.put(someObject);
      }
   }

   public T get() {
      if (isOpen) {
         return lbq.get(0);
      }
   }

   public boolean isOpen() {
      return isOpen;
   }

   public void open() {
      isOpen = true;
   }

   public void close() {
      isOpen = false;
   }
}
```

So your writer thread becomes something like :

```
while (reader.hasNext() ) {
  // read the file and put it into the queue
  dataQ.put(someObject);
} 
// now we're done
dataQ.close();
```

and the reader thread:

```
while (dataQ.isOpen) {
   someObject = dataQ.get();
}
```

You could of course extend the list instead but that gives the user a level of access you might not want. And you need to add some concurrency thingies to this code, like AtomicBoolean.

Comment: I'm passing the Queue to a method. Reading your idea made me have the following. The method could also accept an AtomicBoolean keepProcessing. Then it can run as long as queue.size > 0 || keepProcessing.get()